# Spring Expression Language to convert java.io.File payload to String

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

I have the below snippet in my spring-integration context file:

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="headerEnricherChannel"
        output-channel="xpathHeaderEnricherChannel">
        <!-- java.io.File -->
        <int:header name="DecryptedRequestFile" expression="payload" />
        <!-- java.lang.String -->
        <int:header name="RequestFileName" expression="payload.getName()" />
        <int:header name="Priority"
            expression="#xpath(payload, '//RequestType') == 'SDR_CIRCLE' ? 'SDR_CIRCLE' : #xpath(payload, '//Priority')" />
        <int:header name="savedPayload" expression="payload" />
        **<int:header name="RequestFileAsString"
                    expression="#{ T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).readFileToString(payload) }" />**
    </int:header-enricher>
```

The payload of the input message to `headerEnricherChannel` is `java.io.File`. I want to convert this payload in String using Apache FileUtils. However, doing so throws an error like below. Please can someone point me into the right direction?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#38a1aa85' of type [org.springframework.integration.transformer.support.ExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor] while setting constructor argument with key [RequestFileAsString]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 35): Property or field 'payload' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
```

Answer (score 0):

That expression must as all your others - without `#{}`:

```
<int:header name="RequestFileAsString"
       expression="T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).readFileToString(payload)" />
```

The difference is:

- the first one (with `#{}`) is initialization, one-shot expression. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions-beandef).
- another case is a part of Spring Integration and allows to evaluate an expression at runtime, against each `message`. See everywhere in the Spring Integration Manual.